# Помощь в настройке маршрутиризации

Tags: linux, windows, сеть, freebsd

Пытаюсь сэмулировать в VirtualBox подобную сеть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И не могу сообразить, как правильно прописать маршруты.
В итоге, каждое из 5(2 ПК под Windows, 1 ПК под Linux, шлюз под NetBSD и маршрутиризатор под FreeBSD) устройств должно иметь выход в интернет, и у также каждой устройство должно видеть друг друга. На данный момент, пингуются только находящиеся в одной под сети устройства.

Comment: 1) Проставьте маски 2) Укажите скопы (или пометьте статические адреса) 3) Какая разница, какая ОС на узле? 4) "Устройство NAT" - это в смысле VMNet8 выходит в Инет через NAT?

Comment: 1)Везде 255.255.255.0
2)Для простоты, сейчас везде стоят статические адреса,как указанные на рисунки. Не думаю что они сильно будут влиять. Но вообще - динамические адреса только у WIn2000 и адаптера шлюза выходящего в инет. Скоп 5 - 254.
3) Я не очень опытен в сетях, поэтому различные мелочи которые могут зависеть от ОС меня могут сбить немного с толку.

Comment: 4) Вероятнее всего так. Я на самом деле пытаюсь повторить то, что указано в этой статье http://linux.yaroslavl.ru/docs/conf/vmware_win.html , но в виртуалбоксе.
На данный момент проблема стоит в том, что из линукса я могу пингануть удачно оба адаптера шлюза, со шлюза есть связь с линуксом и интернетом, но у линукса нет доступа в инет. И я не могу понять какой маршрут и на каком устройстве надо прописать. Сегмент с маршрутаризатором и двумя ПК под виндой я ещё не проверял.

Comment: *динамические адреса только у WIn2000 и адаптера шлюза выходящего в инет. Скоп 5 - 254* Это - ошибка. Интерфейсы роутеров, которые встречаются как адреса шлюзов для хотя бы одного из узлов схемы, должны иметь статические адреса.

Answer (score 0):

Маршруты для узлов (не маршрутизаторов!) сети:

---

Подсеть 192.168.32.0/24

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.32.2
route add 192.168.40.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.32.128
route add 192.168.80.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.32.128
route add 192.168.120.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.32.128
```

Подсеть 192.168.40.0/24

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.40.57
route add 192.168.80.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.40.2
route add 192.168.120.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.40.2
```

Подсеть 192.168.80.0/24

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.80.2
```

Подсеть 192.168.120.0/24

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.120.2
```

---

Для маршрутизаторов - выбирать тот набор команд, в котором отсутствуют маршруты в подсети интерфейсов маршрутизатора. Например, для маршрутизатора NetBSD берётся набор для подсети 192.168.40.0/24, поскольку в наборе команд для подсети 192.168.32.0/24 присутствует команда назначения маршрута в подсеть 192.168.40.0/24, в которой находится один из интерфейсов маршрутизатора.